# How to sort manually index of a multindex data frame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have this data frame

```
Risk scoring Sam   1/1  1/2   2/2  3/1  3/2  4/1
Date                                            
August             NaN  1.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
December           6.0  3.0   4.0  2.0  4.0  NaN
January            2.0  NaN   2.0  1.0  2.0  NaN
November           2.0  1.0  12.0  3.0  4.0  1.0
October           14.0  4.0  12.0  4.0  4.0  NaN
September         21.0  3.0   7.0  3.0  2.0  NaN
```

I want this

```
Risk scoring Sam   1/1  1/2   2/2  3/1  3/2  4/1
Date
January            2.0  NaN   2.0  1.0  2.0  NaN
August             NaN  1.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
September         21.0  3.0   7.0  3.0  2.0  NaN  
October           14.0  4.0  12.0  4.0  4.0  NaN
November           2.0  1.0  12.0  3.0  4.0  1.0                                     
December           6.0  3.0   4.0  2.0  4.0  NaN
```

I guess this has to be manually, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is no `MultiIndex`, so use ordered [`CategoricalIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html), then correct working [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
cats = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 
        'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index, ordered=True, categories=cats)

df = df.sort_index()

print (df)
            1/1  1/2   2/2  3/1  3/2  4/1
Date                                     
January     2.0  NaN   2.0  1.0  2.0  NaN
August      NaN  1.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
September  21.0  3.0   7.0  3.0  2.0  NaN
October    14.0  4.0  12.0  4.0  4.0  NaN
November    2.0  1.0  12.0  3.0  4.0  1.0
December    6.0  3.0   4.0  2.0  4.0  NaN
```